# Utilizing AWS javascript SDK when connecting to API Gateway

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I've enabled CORS on my Lambda function and have downloaded the SDK. I want to test utilizing the API Gateway to trigger the Lambda function with a local file. This is an html file that calls a javascript function when a button is pushed. It's running Apache locally to run this test webpage.

Currently, the code for this looks as follows:

```
<button onclick="doFunction()">Download</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/axios/dist/axios.standalone.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/CryptoJS/rollups/hmac-sha256.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/CryptoJS/rollups/sha256.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/CryptoJS/components/hmac.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/CryptoJS/components/enc-base64.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/url-template/url-template.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/apiGatewayCore/sigV4Client.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/apiGatewayCore/apiGatewayClient.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/apiGatewayCore/simpleHttpClient.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/apiGatewayCore/utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="apigClient.js"></script>
<script>
    function doFunction()
    {
        var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient();
        // etc...
```

This snippet follows the tutorial documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk-javascript.html). However, all of these references fail, and as a result, the code can't recognize apigClientFactory. I've attempted adding the downloaded SDK files to the same folder that the file that's running the code is in. I'm really lost as to where I should be pointing and why it's not working. I can't tell if it's an issue with how I've set up CORS, if I need to have some S3 bucket properly referenced, or if I have the SDK files set up incorrectly in the directory. My question is how do I properly import these files from the AWS SDK.

Most of the questions regarding this part of accessing the API Gateway with Javascript use Nodejs or a different setup, which unfortunately is not apart of this process. This question just wants to utilize basic javascript.

Comment: Can you open the `apigClient.js` to see what the name of client factory is? I guess you might have the wrong name of the factory.

Answer (score 0):

I realized what I was doing wrong. The files various files were not located in the correct directory. Basically, the lib folder was not in the same spot as the html file and the apigClient.js. As soon as that happened, all was good!